# Using service inside AppKernel

Tags: php, symfony

I want to define my custom error handlers inside the `AppKernel.php` class - these handler should use logger service. How can I use a service inside the `AppKernel` class?

Comment: Why is it that you want to add the to the `AppKernel`?

Answer (score 0):

*You can do something like*

```
$this->getContainer()->get('my.service.id');
```

*In the file `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php`*

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getContainer()
{
    return $this->container;
}
```